# Unable to retrieve git commits

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project which requires me to checkout older commits of git projects. At times, I get a peculiar error in that despite retrieving a commit hash from git, I am unable to locate it in the log or to pull it.

For example: https://github.com/code4craft/jsoup/commit/4a28f7766124469dbdd5ad6179fe84abff3cd14f

When I pull the main jsoup repository from https://github.com/jhy/jsoup.git

And I try:

```
git checkout 4a28f7766124469dbdd5ad6179fe84abff3cd14f
```

I get:

```
git checkout 4a28f7766124469dbdd5ad6179fe84abff3cd14f
fatal: reference is not a tree: 4a28f7766124469dbdd5ad6179fe84abff3cd14f
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there's no reference pointing to it. In order to be fetched either a branch or a tag must be a descendant of the commit.

So most likely you wouldn't be able to fetch it again.

[Commit exists on GitHub but not in my local clone](https://help.github.com/articles/commit-exists-on-github-but-not-in-my-local-clone)

Comment: Thanks @felipec, I seem to understand that there is no way to retrieve the commit other than asking the author to push it again?

Comment: Not necessarily the author. You need a Git repository that has this object, and then you need to push a reference (tag or branch) that contains this commit.